# Partial name in a string value in a Column

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a long list of names in Column A and its x,y coordinates in column B and C. I want the script to find:

1. a partial string match in the names in column a and also pick the one with the same y coordinates:
2. fine max and min values from x coordinates
3. append ‘start’ to the max x value cell name. Append ‘end’ to the min x value cell name

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLFSV.png)
`

```
  import xlwings as xw

  wb = xw.books.active

      def rename():

        sht = wb.sheets['new Sheet']

dict1 = {}
    ccount = 0
    mr = sht.range(
        'A' + str(wb.sheets[name].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
    for cell in sht.range(f'A2:A{mr}'):
        if 'DAD' in cell.value:
            # x_coord = int(sht.range(f'B{cell.row}').value)
            # y_coord = int(sht.range(f'C{cell.row}').value)
            for yv in sht.range(f'C{cell.row}'):
                if yv.value == yv.offset(1, 0).value:
                    ccount = ccount+1
        if ccount >= 4:
            y_coord = int(sht.range(f'C{yv.row}').value)
            x_coord = int(sht.range(f'B{yv.row}').value)
            if y_coord in dict1:
                dict1[y_coord] += [x_coord]

            else:
                dict1[y_coord] = [x_coord]
    count = 0
    start = 2
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        value.sort(reverse=True)
        for enum, i in enumerate(value, start):
            if enum == start:
                count = 2
                first_name = [f'A{enum}+_START', i, key]
                sht.range(f'A{enum}').value = first_name
            elif enum == len(value)+start-1:
                last_name = [f'A{enum}+_END', i, key]
                sht.range(f'A{enum}').value = last_name
            else:
                between_names = [f'DAD_{count}', i, key]
                sht.range(f'A{enum}').value = between_names
                if enum % 2 == 0:
                    count += 1
```

Comment: Its difficult to fully understand what you are attempting to achieve, other than the 1st sentence and part of the 2nd the rest is unclear. Your code also is not syntactically correct  so it doesn't provide enough clues as to what you're trying to achieve. Please edit your question and expand/clarify your requirements. I may also be useful if you provide the expected output or end result. Please do not provide additional information/clarifications as comments, ensure you edit and add to the question.

Comment: @moken I edited my question. I put a list of items of what I expect the script to do. If it still doesn’t make sense I can add a after/before photo to what I want the script to do

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement and the data you are working with is clearer so now I can give a better example.

The code will create a dictionary using the Y coord as the key and the x cords as values.
Using your updated information; the dictionary 'dict1' would have three keys 67475, 57475 & 47475. All X cordinates that have a name including the text 'DAD' is added to the corresponding Y coord dict key as a value.
Then simply iterate through each key, sort the values in reverse so we know the first item is MAX value and the last is MIN value and then print each Y coord group with generated name and X coord separately.

```
def rename(fn):
    out_sheet = 'Output'  # Name of sheet to write output to
    dict1 = {}  # Dictionary for unsorted data
    header_list = []  # List for headers

    ### Use a context manager with Xlwings
    with xw.App() as app:
        ### Open Workbook and input sheet
        wb = xw.Book(fn)
        sht = wb.sheets['new Sheet']

        ### Get maximum rows in the sheet
        mr = sht.range('A' + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

                          ### Extract the data ###

        ### Iterate column A rows 1 - max rows
        for cell in sht.range(f'A1:A{mr}'):
            ### For row 1 capture the Header text in to list header_list
            if cell.row == 1:
                for header_cell in sht.range(f'A1:C1'):
                    header_list.append(header_cell.value)
                continue
            ### Checks if the text 'DAD' exists in the current cell in the Name column (A)
            ### then adds the x coord to a dictionary with y coord as keys
            if 'DAD' in cell.value.upper():
                ### Create dictionary of cell values that match the criteria using X coord as key
                x_coord = int(sht.range(f'B{cell.row}').value)
                y_coord = int(sht.range(f'C{cell.row}').value)
                if y_coord in dict1:
                    dict1[y_coord] += [x_coord]
                else:
                    dict1[y_coord] = [x_coord]

                            ### Output the data ###

        ### dict1 has 1 key per unique Y coord, Values are all the x coords for that Y coord
        #
        ### Create the sheet 'Output' for write if not exist and assign variable sht2
        if out_sheet not in wb.sheet_names:
            sht2 = wb.sheets.add(out_sheet, after=wb.sheets[0])
            ### Add headers to new sheet
            sht2['A1'].value = header_list
            sht2.range('A1:C1').font.bold = True
        else:
            sht2 = wb.sheets['Output']

        ### Print and write data to the screen and output sheet
        count = 0
        start = 2
        for key, value in dict1.items():
            ### Sort x cords into descending order
            value.sort(reverse=True)
            for enum, i in enumerate(value,start):
                if enum == start:
                    ### First x cord is max value
                    count = 2
                    tstr_start = ['DAD_START', i, key]
                    print(tstr_start, end=' ')
                    sht2.range(f'A{enum}').value = tstr_start
                elif enum == len(value)+start-1:
                    ### Last x cord is min value
                    tstr_end = ['DAD_END', i, key]
                    print(tstr_end)
                    sht2.range(f'A{enum}').value = tstr_end
                else:
                    ### In Between cells use count for the naming
                    ### Use the 'count value that gets incremented every 2nd loop
                    tstr_mid = [f'DAD_{count}', i, key]
                    print(tstr_mid, end=' ')
                    sht2.range(f'A{enum}').value = tstr_mid
                    if enum % 2 == 0:
                        count += 1

                print('')
            start = enum+2
            print('\n--------------\n')

            ### Save Workbook
            wb.save(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'foo.xlsx'
    rename(filename)
```

Comment: thank you. I will test it today. But for the Y coordinate. Some of the cells with DAD name have y coordinates at 67475, 57475, 47475 and so on. I want the script to group the cells with the DAD name and same y coordinates in a group then apply the rename(start, mid, end). Repeat the step with the other groups with the same y coordinates. All that without having to input the value of y coordinates. 
Is there a way to say “ f'C{cell.row}').value == has the same common y value” instead of specifying a value like what you have?

Comment: Certainly, I used 67475 because that was the only value the Y column had in your example which is why your references to checking this value didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have modified the code to handle whatever number of Y coordinates and print them out as separate groups

Comment: Thank you. Why do you have the start to be 2?

Comment: 'start' is the start row of each Y coord group. Since Row 1 is the header the start of group 1 is row 2. 'start' is updated to the first row of the next Y coord group and so on for each group. It's used to determine the first row in the group so the name can set to DAD_START and used in the calculation of the end Row for the name to be set to DAD_END. So does the code sample achieve what you were attempting to produce?

Comment: Thanks again. I tested the first part of the script, where you put the values in a dictionary, and it works. However, I have slightly adjusted the script. The data points I have is 50x the number I have in the example above. I started from first for loop from A2 that way I do not have to worry about the headers. Then I added another for loop for y values to match y values offset(1,0) and only include the counts higher that 4. The reason was to exclude the data with common name with two the same x coordinates to be added to the group. I have updated the script above

Comment: It is taking much longer to run with the adjustment I made. For the second part of the script, I am still testing but I am also going to make an adjustment. for the cell which max, I want to add a '_start' and min to add '_end' to the existing name. for the between and assuming I am starting row3, I want row 4 to match row3 existing name. Then row 6 to match row 5 existing name and so on.

Comment: I tested the out part of the script. It is adding the _start to the wrong cell

Comment: So data is the dictionary is correct its only the writing to the excel sheet that is wrong? I am still working with the example data in and out that you provided intially so is there any update to this to make it easier to understand how things should be processed with the update you have included?

Comment: how do you say if number of values in a key is less than 3 then remove it from the dict1?

Comment: Each grouping will have a length attribute. You can check length for each key in dict1.items() e.g. len(dict1[57475] and remove the key if this length is less less than 3. Or a oneliner like this **dict1 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if len(v) >= 3}** will create a new dictionary where the length of the values is greater or equal than 3. Since it has the same name as dict1 it will overwrite the old dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. From the enum, i in enumerator(value,start), is there away to return the row number instead of using the start = 2? I want to use the row number to apply it in range(A) and use that change A values. The data I have does not start in row 2 and the current output script is changing the wrong cell.

Comment: As the last code example stands I did not preserve the names from column A since the naming you had indicated was required was not based on any existing text in these cells. Therefore the dictionary only holds the Y coord as key with X coords as values. To keep the original name text would require a re-do [dict1] to capture this info as well. ***Update** Maybe you have changed your need for that since the comment has been deleted.

Comment: enum is just a count for a loop. It increments as the loop cycles. By default starts from 0 and counts by 1 up to the end of the loop range. You can specify different start value, i.e. start from 1, 2, 5 etc & you can set the step, i.e. the amount it increments per loop. In the case enumerate is being used in my code sample rows are being written to, enum is used to determine the current row.

Comment: The line **enumerate(value,start)** tells enum to start counting from the value of variable 'start' which is 2 if you want it to start from another number change 'start's value or physically set to another number like **enumerate(value,4)**

Comment: Thanks. The example I shared, it was a bad example. I will try to post the actual data and how i want to look . But the number of data points I have is about 20k and a total of 192 out of 20k with the key word DAD. That said, I do not know where my dictionary values, key located in the spreadsheet. They could be in row 50 or 100 or scattered. That was I can’t specify my starting row if I don’t know the row.  is there away to get the row number from Key, value after sorting the first group? Or is there to do this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with updating your code and reviewing what you have learnt then asking a new question(s). The dictionary hold the values that are added to it. In the example code provided there are no row numbers saved just the Y co-ord and the X co-ords with that Y co-cord. Dictionaies can include additional data can be a dictionary of dictionarys or lists with multiple values, so this info may be included however it may get complicated. For what you ultimately need to do a dictionary may not be the best option.

Comment: after sorting the values. would this make sense to get the row value?                                                           for enum, i in enumerate(value):
            if enum == 0:
                if int(sht.range('f'B{cell.row}').value') == i and sht.range('C') == key:
                    nrow = int(sht.range((f'B{cell.row}')).row)

Comment: There is no row value until you put something in a cell and that is what enum is for, determining which row to write to. **if int(sht.range('f'B{cell.row}').value')** would give you and error with single quote around the f string.

Comment: But the enum value only gives you the numbers of at the dictionary level but not the actual rows in the spreadsheet. That is why when I try rewrite the values in column A referencing enum, it is changing the wrong cell. I am thinking to use the match formula after sorting to get the cell row. Then use it to change value in column A reference the row from the match equation

Comment: enum is the row that the dictionary data is being written to. It's not appending to the sheet, the values are written to a cell where the row is specified by enum.

Comment: how do you sort a value of a list based on first number?{67475: [(1425, 7), (1675, 8), (1925, 9), (2175, 10), (2425, 11), (2675, 12), (2925, 13), (3175, 14), (3425, 15), (3675, 16)}

Comment: Sort using the 1st number in the bracketed numbers which are values to the key 67475. Assume the dictionary is 'dict' Separate the values **for key, values in dict.items():**, then just sort on 'values' **values.sort()**. Though in this case it wont do anything since those numbers are already in order (unless you want descending, so use reverse=True as a param in sort). btw the dictionary is missing the close square bracket.

Comment: They are not sorted based on the first value. So I added x coordinates and row number(xcoord, row number). now once I sorted the lists based on x value. Then I can use the row to get exact cell in column A to change the value there. But how do you sort the lists based on the first value(xvalue)?

Comment: The xvalue is the first number in the bracketed value, right? so for **(1425, 7), (1675, 8), (1925, 9)...** the xvalue is 1425, 1675, 1925? If so if you had a dict **dict = {67475: [(2425, 11), (1425, 7), (1925, 9)]}** the sort in the last comment would change the values list to **(1425, 7) (1925, 9) (2425, 11)**

Comment: Ok thanks. Then if I want to called the second value dict[value][1]?

Comment: The bracketed value (1425, 7) is a tuple, so 1425 is [0] and 7 is [1]. However from the dictionary itself it would be **dict[key][0][1]** since there are lists in the dictionary key 67475 and this value is a subordinate of the lists. ie dictionary key, then which list, then which element in the list. **dict[value][1]** would return the second tuple.